# Is there a way to make org-mode count repetitive tasks done certain hours past midnight as done in the previous day?

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

A lot of times we sleep after 12 o'clock, and some of the tasks that are done before we sleep will be counted as being done in the second day, which causes the repetition schedule to be a bit messed up. This is especially annoying for `org-habit`, since it will then say there's a break in the middle of the habit chain and that you've actually done the task for the following day instead, which forces you to manually edit the timestamps in the affected tasks to get the counting right again. In the flashcard app [Anki](http://ankisrs.net), there is an option to treat cards finished certain hours past midnight as still being finished in the last day. I wonder if a similar functionality is available/can be configured in `org-mode`?

Comment: Near [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899325/change-the-hour-when-org-mode-is-starting-new-day); check the variable `org-extend-today-until`

Comment: @Juancho However it seems this variable doesn't work with org-habit, and will actually a kind of confuse it. Maybe it should be a feature request for org-habit and repetitive tasks in org mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq org-extend-today-until 4
      org-use-effective-time t)
```

That will:

1. `org-extend-today-until`: Treat 4 AM as the time when the following day begins (instead of midnight)
2. `org-use-effective-time`: If you're up at say 1 AM like me right now, treat the time when you mark a TODO as done as 23:59 of the previous day, sensu stricto