# How to make org-habit shift between days at 04:00 instead of midnight?

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

`org-habit` keeps track of my habits, e.g. taking a piece of melatonin pill every day before bed. Sometimes I go to sleep after midnight. I don't want the habit to count as failed in this case. I want `orgmode` and `org-habit` let me check the habit before or after midnight. How do I do that?

Right now I have it scheduled like this: `SCHEDULED: <2017-10-04 Wed .+1d>`

The other problem is that if I check it at 2 am, then it list it in the agenda on that day even if I want to go to sleep before midnight.

Comment: [Related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17302/is-there-a-way-to-make-org-mode-count-repetitive-tasks-done-certain-hours-past-m?rq=1) with no good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set:

```
(setq org-extend-today-until 4)
```

And then use either `org-agenda-todo` to mark a habit as done after midnight or `org-agenda-todo-yesterday` to mark it done before midnight, as you prefer.

Alternatively, see the [related link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17302/is-there-a-way-to-make-org-mode-count-repetitive-tasks-done-certain-hours-past-m?rq=1) that Juancho pointed to for how to make `org-agenda-todo` (and `org-todo`) always use the previous "clock day" when marking items as done in the small hours of the morning.